# Inno Setup запустить файл из кода и подождать его завершения

Tags: pascal, install, inno-setup

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Inno Setup запустить файл из кода и подождать его завершения, а так же узнать код завершения для запускаемого приложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно использовать функцию [Exec](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec).

В документации есть пример:

```
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  // Launch Notepad and wait for it to terminate
  if Exec(ExpandConstant('{win}\notepad.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
     ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    // handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code
  end
  else begin
    // handle failure if necessary; ResultCode contains the error code
  end;
end;
```

Здесь нужно обратить внимание на переменную `ResultCode` она передаётся в функцию по ссылке, и после выполнение функции в неё будет записан код завершения.

Флаг `ewWaitUntilTerminated` заставляет ожидать завершение вызванной команды.

Вот пример установки MSI пакета:

```
procedure InstallMsi(FilePath, InstallFolderPath: string; var RebootRequired: boolean);
var
    ResultCode: integer;
begin
  Exec('msiexec.exe', '/quiet /i "' + FilePath + '" AGREETOLICENSE=yes INSTALLFOLDER="' + InstallFolderPath + '"' , '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
  if ResultCode = ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED then
    RebootRequired := true
  else if ResultCode <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    RaiseException(CustomMessage('MsiInstallationError'));
end;
```