# Java открытие приложения от файла

Tags: java

Есть Desktop на Java. Я сохраняю данные в файл через JChooser, и через него же открываю. Сделал помощью launch4j exe. С помощью Inno setup сделать установщик. Теперь не пойму как обработать открытие какого-либо файла.

Как я понимаю необходимо сделать проверку при пуске приложения и получить путь к файлу. Как это сделать? или есть другие способы?
Всё это делается сейчас на Windows 7.

**UPDATE**

Немного разъясню. В итоге я имею файл с сохранением. Допустим как у Word. Inno setup устанавливает настройки так, что этот файл можно запустить с помощью программы. Вопрос в том, как обработать в самой программе, что её запустили из файла, а не просто запуск. И как прочитать расположение файла с которого запустили

Comment: Как запустить файл описано здесь: [Inno Setup запустить файл из кода и подождать его завершения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742419/inno-setup-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/742769#742769). Это вам подходит?

Comment: В рамках всего инсталлера можно посмотреть здесь: [Inno Setup установка дополнительного ПО](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683318/inno-setup-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%9F%D0%9E/684684#684684)

Comment: @MaLS  Так понятнее?

Comment: Не очень. Но правильно ли я понял? Вы хотите, чтобы после установки программы, Windows открывал специфичные файлы в вашей программе? Например, как для программы Word, файлы с расширением docx Windows по двойному щелчку пользователя открывает в программе Word?

Comment: @Mals с помощью inno setup, по двойному щелчку на файл открывается мой exe. Вопрос в том, как при запуске программы получить путь к этому файлу. К примеру тыкаешь на docx и открывается этот файл в Word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался прост. При запуске приложения по двойному клику, в командной строке передаётся путь к файлу. Соответственно он записывается в массив String args, который в главном методе main(). Соответственно необходимо просто получить нулевой аргумент. И открыть по этому пути файл.